# selenium with golang easy way to get url

Tags: selenium, go

on python get url code is quite easy just four lines

```
    URL = 'https://google.com'
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(URL)
```

so I thought it was easy golang too

I've searched many golang code reference but it quite large and complicate code to me

can you help me to get url with golang easily?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need selenium for that
Here's the code

```
package main

import "github.com/fedesog/webdriver"

chromeDriver := webdriver.NewChromeDriver("./chromedriver") // Driver path
chromeDriver.Start()
desired := webdriver.Capabilities{"Platform": "MAC"}
required := webdriver.Capabilities{}
session, _ := chromeDriver.NewSession(desired, required)
session.Url("https://www.google.com")
```

hope it works to you

ciao!